# How to force log in on a certain page

Tags: magento-1.9, login

We have a quick order page where customer can enter all their shopping list then order it will one click. However we want to force the customer to log in as the majority of our customers have special prices and cant see these unless they are logged in.

Is there a way of creating a pop up forcing the customer to log in before the can view the page?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing an if statement to display the content if the customer is logged in and displays a warning message if they are not then adding the logg in form to the .xml file As you can see below

```
    <?php 
     $login = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' )->isLoggedIn(); //Check if User is Logged In
     if($login)
   {}
else {}    ?>
```

then add

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" />
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

To the XML file